# Javascript not working on blackberry 5.0 devices

Tags: javascript, blackberry, cross-browser, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

I have a website created in hybrid css,html and javascript used. It works well on bb7.0 devices browser . But not on 5.0 devices browser.How can I check which devices support which javascripts or how can I test for the same.

Comment: To those people who down voted this question - why?

Answer (score 1):

Browser support was improved in OS 5.0 and completely re-written in OS 6.0, so my experience is that Browser experience on OS 6.0 is OK (screen size considered) anything prior to OS 6.0 is not so great experience and prior to OS 5.0, the experience can be pretty poor.

The User Agent can be used to determine the level of Browser, see this article for further information:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-detect-the-BlackBerry-Browser/ta-p/559862

Now with respect to JavaScript support, be aware that users can turn off JavaScript on the BB Browser options.  But the following link may help you decide what JavaScript options are available to you.  Sorry this is not an area of expertise:

[JavaScript Information for OS 5.0 and below](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/Feature_JavaScript_512506_11.jsp)

Sorry I have not been able to find an equivalent for the later Browsers, but I think that is because it is fully supported.